# SQL Server Migration Assistant Migration Stops Roughly After 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I am migrating about 6 million records from a MySql 5.7 DB to SQL Server 2012 using Sql Server Migration Assistant v7.10. I have set the batch size to 1000 and migration time out to 30 minutes under SSMA project settings.

Every time I run the migrations, it stops roughly around 10 minutes. SSMA report says, migration complete with a ~92% success rate, and no errors. Below is a screen shot of the migration report. Any ideas how to fix this?

[SSMA migration report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTo1q.png)

UPDATE: There was a row in the MySql table that was not readable. Data migration worked after we removed that row.

Comment: Why is MySQL tagged here.. MySQL is not the same as SQL Server (MSSQL)..

Comment: Do you have some rows that cannot be converted?

Comment: @DanielBlais I can read all rows and they are all text fields. If they can't be converted, that should trow an error, right?

Comment: @RaymondNijland MySql is tagged because I'm migrating from a MySQL DB